# saving camera images in custom location in the phone memory

Tags: android, image, file, camera, save

I am trying to take a picture and save it to a custom location in the phone memory. Every time I have tried the image was saved into the default location of the application **/data/data/[package]**. I want to stored in the custom location like **/emulated/0/My_clicks/**. I am **not using any sd card** so I want to save images on the **phone memory**. When I search on Google I got images saved in public folder on the sd card, not in the custom location.

My code looks like this:

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public void onCreateView(.....)
{
  // ...
        mphotobutton=(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_imagebutton);

        mphotobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_PHOTO);
            }
        });
  // ...

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data)
{
        if(requestcode==REQUEST_PHOTO)   
        {

            String filename=data.getStringExtra(SecondFragment.EXTRA_PHOTO_FILENAME);
            if(filename!=null)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "filenam: " + filename);

                Photo p =new Photo(filename);

                Log.i(TAG,"Crime: "+mCrime.getTitle() +" has a photo");


                BitmapDrawable b=null;

                if(p!=null)
                {
                    String path = getActivity().getFileStreamPath(p.getfilename()).getAbsolutePath();

                    b=PictureUtils.getScaledDrawable(getActivity(),path);
                }

                mphotoview.setImageDrawable(b);

            }

        }

}
```

**SecondFragment.java**

```
public void onCreateView(....)
{
   // ...

    takepicturebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        if(mcamera!=null)
                        mcamera.takePicture(mshuttercallback,null,mjpegcallback);
                    }
    });

  ...


}  //  onCreateView()

private Camera.ShutterCallback mshuttercallback= new Camera.ShutterCallback()
{
    public void onShutter()
            {
                    // display the progress indicator
                    mprogresscontainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
};

private Camera.PictureCallback mjpegcallback=new Camera.PictureCallback()
{
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
            //create a filename
             String filename= UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".jpg";

            // save the jpeg data to disk
            FileOutputStream os=null;
            boolean success=true;

            try
            {
                os=getActivity().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                os.write(data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG,"Error writing to file "+filename,e);
                success=false;
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    if(os!=null)
                    os.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Error closing file "+filename,e);
                    success=false;
                }
            } // finally

            if(success)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "JPEG saved at " + filename);
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO_FILENAME,filename);
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
            }
            else
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

            getActivity().finish();

    } // onPictureTaken()

};  // mjpegcallback
```

## **AnroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

The picture is saved in SecondActivity fragment called **SecondFragment.java**. How can I save an image to the custom location in the phone memory (eg: **/storage/emulated/0/my_click/**) NOT IN SD CARD (I am not using any sd card)? How can I code for saving image?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) will give you the path to /storage/emulated/0/Documents. You also need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Note that for Android, external storage is not (necessarily) SD CARD.

Answer (score 0):

finally i made the solution....THANKS TO Alex Cohn

look on the code above and compare with below one

first make sure make folder "**My_clicks**" in the directory "**/storage/emulated/0/**" using java code or manually make your own...i did manually

## SecondFragment.java

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mjpegcallback=new Camera.PictureCallback()
```

{

```
    ......

    }
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
                {

                    String filename="MrCrime-"+new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date())+".jpg";

                    // save the jpeg data to disk
                    FileOutputStream os=null;
                    boolean success=true;


                    //  getExternalStorageDirectory()  ==>  this method return directory path "/storage/emulated/0/"  THANKS TO Alex Cohn
                    String imagepath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/My_clicks/"+filename;

                    File imagefile=new File(imagepath);

                    try
                    {

                        os=new FileOutputStream(imagefile);


                        //os=getActivity().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        os.write(data);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG,"Error writing to file "+filename,e);
                        success=false;
                    }

            .........
```

}  //  mjpegcallback

## FirstFragment.java

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data)
{
        if(requestcode==REQUEST_PHOTO)   
        {

            String imagename=data.getStringExtra(SecondFragment.EXTRA_PHOTO_FILENAME);
            if(imagename!=null)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "imagename: " + imagename);

                Photo p =new Photo(imagename);

                Log.i(TAG,"Crime: "+mCrime.getTitle() +" has a photo");

                //Photo p = mCrime.getphoto();
                BitmapDrawable b=null;

                if(p!=null)
                {
                    //String path = getActivity().getFileStreamPath(p.getfilename()).getAbsolutePath();

                     //String filename = p.getfilename();
                     String imagepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/My_clicks/"+imagename;

                    b=PictureUtils.getScaledDrawable(getActivity(),imagepath);
                }

                mphotoview.setImageDrawable(b);

            }

        }

}
```

HOPE SOME ONE WILL HELPFULL......